# Read Excel to datatable without losing precision for currency type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to read an Excel sheet data to a datatable for binding to a GridView. My Excel sheet contains data as follows,

```
ID    Value1                    Value2
-------------------------------------------------
1     $312976.97530297          $30790.0614862584
etc
```

I'm using the following code to read the values to a datatable.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string filePath = @"D:\Book1.xlsx";
string strConn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"", filePath);
using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConn)) 
{
using (OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID, value1,value2  FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConnection))
dbAdapter.Fill(table);
}
```

Problem: since value1 and value2 contain $ symbol, dataAdaptor retrieve both the values without full precision, ie. instead of 312976.97530297, its return 312976.9753 only.

```
Note: 
1. I cannot change the input Excel sheet since the enduser will upload it to the web site.
2. If i remove the $ symbol in the excel sheet, it will return the full precision, but $ also present in the input sheet.
3. I tried using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and its working, but the performance is very low.


Or I can format all the excel cell as Text/General type before filling to the datatable, Anyone knows how to do that?
```

Please suggest one method using OleDbDataAdapter.

Thanks in Advance,
Wilson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@All,
Finally i have done it in a complex way :),
1. Formatting all the excel colums to General type after uploading using interop
2. Read the excel to a datatable using oledbadaptor.(now i'm getting the full precision in the tatatable since the cell type is General)
3. Now i'm converting the datatable row type to string since i need to insert the datatable values to SQL table using UDT(without converting we will loss the precision here also)

Anyway its working fine now (an alternative approach always welcome :)  )
Wilz...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/79802 a try. It can read data very fast, at least compared to interop. Also, interop is not reliable enough for a webservice.

For your problem: Maybe there is a way to escape "$"

Microsoft advises to use double or float datatype in case of Currencies. What format does you use?

Comment: Christian, Thanks for the response, I'm using double datatype in C#. Its seems like there is no proper solution for this issue :(

Comment: Or I can format all the excel cell as Text/General type before filling to the datatable, Anyone knows how to do that?